# Flex reducing space between two bars+

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

[image]

Is it possoble to reduce the space between two bar of different elements. If yes with which property? thank you

Comment: i tried using barWidthRatio property but the distance between bars remains th same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

barWidthRatio should work with a little "hack" from layout. I wrote a test app for you that should do what you want. Changing the barWidthRatio from 0.4 to 1.1 ie. should look like from:

[image: barWidthRation = 0.4]

to:

[image: barWidthRatio = 1.1]

see code here (still Flex 3.6):
http://pastie.org/3314808